# Retrieve column names from HDF5 store using Pytables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5, pytables

I have a database with following column structure

```
  A,    B ,    C
       /      
|b1, b2, b3|
```

In this structure 'B' has sub-columns  `b1,b2, b3` i.e. column B has array of 
entries. I have found that `b1,b2, b3` have different column name as well, using

```
pandas.read_hdf("h5store.h5", "r")
```

When we do

```
import tables

table  = .... # HDF5 table

colname = table.colnames  #table column names
```

MY question is how to get 2nd level column name i.e. for `b1,b2, b3`?